# Strange behavior in PHP for MAC

Tags: php

I have a problem in Mac Snow Leopard.

If i put a php file on the WebServer with the phpinfo() and i call from the command line

```
php -r 'phpinfo();'
```

I get different results even if they (apparently) point to the same php.ini

How can i know the differences between the "two" phps?

Comment: Do you mean you have 2 different PHP versions? What "differences" do you want to know?

Answer (score 0):

If you are positively sure that you've indeed got 2 php's, try this: http://www.quickdiff.com/ which lets you compare 2 text files (php.ini1 to php.ini2). If you've only got one php.ini file, make sure that if you ever upgraded the PHP version that it was done so correctly, as any old remnants that contain the version number may be throwing the result off. If possible, please post the results of your PHPInfo tests. Thanks, and good luck. If both of the above statements came back normal, maybe it's a bug. But I highly doubt it's mac-only. I'll look into it further if you can post your results and still not solve it.